# $.post() why i am not getting the alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i wont to pass the 2 values to a jsp page and return some data i test it with alerts and my values are correct without the $.post()

```js
function deleteFunction(courseId, userId) {
    $.post('../controlers/doDelete.jsp', {courseId: courseId, userId: userId}, function (data) {
      alert("somthing here");  
    });
    
    location.reload();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span onclick="deleteFunction('<%=c.getCourse_id()%>','<%=me.getId()%>');">click me</span>
```

Comment: Clearly `location.reload();` will stop anything the ajax is doing.

Comment: "can't get it to work" is not helpful for anyone. Please post questions here, but also please be specific about what the problem is. If you're looking for copy-and-paste support of scripts, you should try a forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `location.reload();` in that spot will reload the page prior to the return of the AJAX call. `$.post()` produces an asynchronous operation. That is, the call fires to the server and the script keeps executing while it's waiting for a return.

If you're wanting the call to return ***before*** the page reloads try the following code:

```
function deleteFunction(courseId, userId) {
    $.post('../controlers/doDelete.jsp', {courseId: courseId, userId: userId}, function (data) {
        alert("somthing here");
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

The function being passed to `$.post()` is a callback that occurs ***after*** the ajax call has been returned. By adding the `location.reload();` to the callback function, you're allowing the call to complete, providing an opportunity for you to do something with the returned data (in this case fire an `alert`) and then, upon completion of the previous operations, reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you use $.ajax() and pass it the `asynch : false` option.

```js
function deleteFunction(courseId, userId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../controlers/doDelete.jsp',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    asynch: false,
    data: {
      courseId: courseId,
      userId: userId
    }
  }).done(function(data) {

    alert("something here");
  });

  location.reload();
}
```

`asynch : false` forces ajax to run synchronously, therefore, the script stops and waits until the ajax request has finished, rather than the ajax running in the background.